# Sendmail relay without authentication

Tags: linux, authentication, sendmail, smtp

I have an issue:when the email is sent from an address other than 127.0.0.1  the authorization is required even if ip is on the same machine.

How can I avoid to make request authorization for a given ip ?

Answer (score 1):

Use acces table with the following entry (change IP address as needed):

```
connect:192.168.0.1 RELAY
```

https://www.sendmail.com/sm/open_source/docs/m4/anti_spam.html#access_db